# How to fit the label of a fit in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit

The label of a fit can be placed relatively to it like:

```
    \documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,fit,backgrounds}

\tikzstyle{back}=[rectangle,
fill=blue!30,
inner sep=0.2cm,
rounded corners=3mm]

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,on grid,auto] 
    \node[] (1) {\textbf{1}}; 
    \node[] (2) [right= of 1]  {\textbf{2}}; 

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [back,
    fit=(1) (2),
    label=above:{\tiny Introduction}] {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But what if I want to shift that label, for example, to the right? How should I use `\xshift` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

See also [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,fit,backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    back/.style={rectangle,
    fill=blue!30,
    inner sep=0.2cm,
    rounded corners=3mm},
    }

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1cm,on grid,auto] 
    \node (1) {\textbf{1}}; 
    \node (2) [right= of 1] {\textbf{2}}; 

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node [back,
            fit=(1) (2),
            label={[xshift=2mm]above:{\tiny Introduction}}] {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to specify options for a label in square brackets, see [TikZ documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) page 239f.
Because you have not provided a *complete* example I have based this answer on an example from the [TikZ documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) page 240:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz \node [rectangle,draw,label={[red, xshift=1em]center:R}] {main node};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it doesn't work in the case of the OP's intention.

Comment: `label={[xshift=2mm]above}:{\tiny Introduction}] {};` doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't downvote since the answerer may fix the problem.

Comment: @A.Loc `label={[xshift=2mm]above:{\tiny Introduction}}]` works for me, you forgot a `}` after Introduction.

Comment: @A.Loc As CarLaTeX says, pay attention to the position of the braces. You want braces around the *entire* label construct, options, position and the text itself, i.e. `label={ ... }`, not `label={..}:{..}`. So the closing brace before the `:` is wrong, you want just `{[xshift=2mm]above:\tiny Introduction}`, which is the same construct as in jakun's answer.